# How to fix 'ImportError: cannot import name bin_user'

Tags: python, pip

```
File "/home/shuo/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
File "/home/shuo/.opt/platform_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.commands import commands, get_similar_commands, get_summaries
File "/home/shuo/.opt/platform_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip.commands.bundle import BundleCommand
File "/home/shuo/.opt/platform_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/bundle.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip.commands.install import InstallCommand
File "/home/shuo/.opt/platform_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pip.req import InstallRequirement, RequirementSet, parse_requirements
File "/home/shuo/.opt/platform_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
File "/home/shuo/.opt/platform_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
ImportError: cannot import name bin_user
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 system. 
Please help me fixing this problem.

Comment: Please show your code!

Comment: How did you install pip? Through `easy_install` or `apt install python-pip`? What were you trying to install?

Comment: @gonczor through  sudo apt-get install python-pip, I just want to check upgrade of pip, then the error show up

Comment: I have the same error traceback. It happens when I try to install python-setuptools through Zypper. I'm using SLES12-SP2-12.2-0.
Does anyone have any thought on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:
uninstall python-pip rpm package. Then completely remove the directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
Then reinstall rpm package python-pip.